# Pandas dataframe, select column by boolean values in matching dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1, and a second df2, which for each column from df1 contains a boolean value:

First dataframe (df1):

```
col01 | col02 | col03 | ... | col10
```

second (df2):

```
col   |  keep
------------
col01 | True
col02 | False
col03 | False
col04 | False
col05 | True

...
col10 | True
------------
```

I want to keep only the columns in df1 that are marked as True in df2 (so, in my example I would remove col02, col03 and col04), but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I was thinking I could convert the 'keep' column from df2 in a list (with only the True elements) and use something like:

```
df1.drop(columns=[col for col in df1 if col not in list_keep], inplace=True)
```

but I was wondering if there's a faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first filter values to list and then select only existing in `df1` by [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
L = df2.loc[df2['keep'], 'col'].tolist()

df = df1[df1.columns.intersection(L)]
```

Or with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df = df1.loc[:, df1.columns.isin(L)]
```