# Extract x column values based on other y column boolean True values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one pandas dataframe (xy):

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | True |
| value2 | True |
| value3 | False |
| value4 | True |
| value5 | False |
| value6 | True |

The objective would be to extract the values ​​from column x that appear in column y with, based on the Boolean values ​​'True' from table y, to a list.

Here's what i tried so far, with no success (ref: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230827/pandas-dataframe-select-column-by-boolean-values-in-matching-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com)):

`lst = (xy['x'].loc[:, xy['x'].isin(xy['y'])]).tolist()`

Here's the result i expect:

`[value1, value2, value4, value6]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to filter:

```
df = df[df['y']]
```

And then convert to list:

```
lst = df['x'].tolist()
```

Comment: Don't use python keywords as variable name, please.

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name. It's a standard python function. Also `df = df[df['y']]` overwrites the dataframe, thus losing all lines that do not have `True` in the column `y`.

Comment: works fine, however for some reason, the first element of the list is coming as '\ufeffvalue1'. perhaps it as to do with my working environment and not the solution itself...

Comment: @Corralien - thanks for the remark and edit. You are right!

Answer (score 1):

first, you filter the dataframe to get only the lines where `y` contains the value `True`.

```py
df[df['y']]
```

You then take the `x` column of this filtered dataframe, which now only contains the rows where `y` contains the value `True`

```py
df[df['y']]['x']
```

Finally, you convert it into a list with `.tolist()` :

```py
print(df[df['y']]['x'].tolist())
```

will output

```py
['value1', 'value2', 'value4', 'value6']
```